# linking content in the body of html

Tags: html

I have two websites that are hosted in their own sub-domain of the main domain site

some pages I would like the content to be matching with only having to edit one site

currently I am doing this using iframe to link the content so I edit a file on the main-domain and the changes are reflected on both sub domains

how ever I would prefer to use something like

$body="main-domain.com/edits/test.html

so that I am not given additional scrolls

I don't want to hide the scrolls on the iframe as this hides content, and I dont want to set page height as this ends up with pages with dead space

any advice please

Comment: Use a Content Management System

Comment: Is HTML your only possible language?

Comment: you could try jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Comment: I'm open to using PHP, ideally what I need to do is pull contact information from my main domain to show on my sub domains.      I want to pull the div with I'd content so that the header and footer are omitted

Comment: Sorted, the problem was my absolute path, what I thought was my absolute path wasn't now a simple phone call is that was needed ... Thanks anyway